# Run a command with guaranteed exit code 0 in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile in which I need to run a `test` by executing a command say `long_testing_commad`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM awesome:image
RUN abc
RUN long_testing_commad
RUN xyz
```

`long_testing_commad` sometimes fail, and that causes `docker build` to fail saying "got a non-zero exit status from `long_testing_commad`".

What can I do in my `Dockerfile` so that no matter what happens with `long_testing_commad` the build process goes on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not best practice, but the easiest way would be:

```
RUN long_testing_commad || true
```

Comment: I like it Dirty :). Thanks.